# Finite Cyclic Group - for each $x$, $x$ to the power of the group's order is the identity.

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, finite-groups

We know that, if G is finite cyclic group, then for each $x\in G$, $$x^{\left|G\right|}=e$$

So I have an easy exercize, to show that $U_8$ isnt cyclic (Without lagrange or something more complicated).

So, of course first of all I checked manualy if there is a generator, and I didnt find one, so it isnt cyclic.

But accroding to the state below, is it correct to say, that if exists $x\in G$ and $x^{\left|G\right|}\ne e$ then it isnt cyclic ?

But the more interesting thing that in this group that condition $x^{\left|G\right|}=e$ applies every element in the group, but it isnt cyclic eather.

So from that I conclud that it is only one direction true, if I have a group and $x^{\left|G\right|}=e$ for each x in it, it doesnt mean that it is cyclic, right ?

Must be there a generator, it is the main condition by definition.

Comment: But in every finite group $x^{|G|}=e$ always, regardless whether it is cyclic or not. To show that a group is not cyclic, you either have to test all elements (as you did), or show that there are more than $\varphi(a)$ elements of order $a$.

Comment: what is 'a' in the second method (Euler Function)?

Comment: $a$ is a divisor of $|G|$ (i.e. a possible order).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In every finite group we have $x^{\left|G\right|}=e$ for all $x$.

A finite group is not cyclic iff there is $0<m<\left|G\right|$ such that $x^m=e$ for all $x$.

You'll find that $m=2$ works for $U_8$, which has order $4$. In particular, there is no element of order $4$ and so $U_8$ cannot be cyclic.