# Find the structure of $\mathbb{Z}_{120}^*$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic, modules, abelian-groups, cyclic-groups

How to find the structure (in term of cyclic groups) of $\mathbb{Z}_{120}^*$?

I know that the number of elements of $\mathbb{Z}_{120}^*= \phi(120) = 32 = 2^5$

But then, any hints?

Comment: Are you familiar with the Chinese remainder theorem?

Comment: Yes, I am familiar with it

Comment: Ok, then Use that to write the ring $\mathbb{Z}_{120}$ as a direct product first.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}_{120} = \mathbb{Z}_{3} \times \mathbb{Z}_{8} \times \mathbb{Z}_{5}$ 
Then I can study the group of invertibles as $\mathbb{Z}_{120}^* = \mathbb{Z}_{3}^* \times \mathbb{Z}_{8}^* \times \mathbb{Z}_{5}^*$. The first and the third are easy because are cyclic of order $2$ and $4$, the second is of order $4$ but not cyclic so it has to be the Klein group $ \mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{2}$

Comment: Looks good. You can write that up and answer you own question then, to get some feedback on the presentation also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I want to thank Tobias Kildetoft for the useful suggestion of using the **Chinese Remainder Theorem**.

So we have that $120 = 8 \; 3 \; 5$

$\mathbb{Z}_{120} = \mathbb{Z}_{3} \times \mathbb{Z}_{8} \times \mathbb{Z}_{5}$

And from this

$\mathbb{Z}_{120}^* = \mathbb{Z}_{3}^* \times \mathbb{Z}_{8}^* \times \mathbb{Z}_{5}^*$

Now, from a general result: $\mathbb{Z}_{p}^* = \mathbb{Z}_{p-1}$ if $p$ is a prime integer.

$\mathbb{Z}_{8}^*$ has $4$ elements, it could be either $\mathbb{Z}_{4}$ or $\mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{2}$. But it is not cyclic since $\mathbb{Z}_{8}^* = \{1,3,5,7 \}$ and so we see it has no element of order $4$  , and so we have the desired decomposition:

$\mathbb{Z}_{120}^* = \mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{4}$

Comment: Great. You may want to be a little more specific with why $\mathbb{Z}_8^*$ is not cyclic though.

Comment: For that last bit, see http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1396025/589.